# PDFBox - Delete image from the page and add same image on different position

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 2.x version and need to **reposition the existing image** from the page. For that, I'm removing the image from the page and adding it back again. But with my current implementation, it is not showing either image.

Please help me with this and let me know where I'm going wrong.

```
try {
  PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("..\\sampleWithImage_with_barcode_img.pdf"));

  PDDocument newDocument = new PDDocument();
  for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    PDPage sourcePage = document.getPage(i);
    PDPage pdPage = newDocument.importPage(sourcePage);
    pdPage.setResources(sourcePage.getResources());

    //To remove existing from the page
    stripUnusedImages(pdPage, newDocument);

    //ADD OTHER IMAGE
    PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("D:\\copy\\pic.jpg", newDocument);

    PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(newDocument, pdPage,
      PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);

    // Drawing the image in the PDF document
    contents.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, 50, 30);

    System.out.println("Image inserted Successfully.");

    // Closing the PDPageContentStream object
    contents.close();
  }
  newDocument.save("..\\RemovedImage.pdf");
  document.close();
  newDocument.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

//Method to remove image
protected void stripUnusedImages(PDPage page, PDDocument document) throws IOException, XmpParsingException {
  PDResources resources = copyResources(page);
  PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
  parser.parse();

  List < Object > tokens = parser.getTokens();
  System.out.println("Total Tokens=" + tokens.size());
  List < Object > newTokens = new ArrayList < Object > ();
  for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
    Object token = tokens.get(j);
    if (token instanceof COSName) {
      COSName cosname = (COSName) token;
      PDXObject o = resources.getXObject(cosname);
      if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
        PDImageXObject pdImageXObject = (PDImageXObject) o;
        if (pdImageXObject.getMetadata() != null) {
          System.out.println("pdImageXObjec metadata exist");
          newTokens.remove(newTokens.size() - 1);
          continue;
        }
      }
    }

    newTokens.add(token);
  }

  PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
  OutputStream outputStream = newContents.createOutputStream();
  ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(outputStream);
  writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
  outputStream.close();
  newContents.addCompression();
  page.setContents(newContents);
}
```

Comment: for the PDPageContentStream constructor, try adding a fifth "true" parameter

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Thanks for your response but unfortunately it has not worked.

Comment: Check the crop box of your page: Do you possibly position the image outside of it?

Comment: @mkl The below piece of code helped me. As per @Tilman Hausherr suggestion added **true** as a fifth param value in PDPageContentStream constructor which reset the graphic context and as per my requirement changed AppendMode **from APPEND to PREPEND** in 3rd param value.
                                                                                                                                       `new PDPageContentStream(newDocument, pdPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, true, true);`

Please add this as an answer because answers not accepting from my account.

Answer (score 0):

The `PDPageContentStream` is constructed like this:

```
PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(newDocument, pdPage,
  PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
```

Tilman Hausherr in a comment proposed *adding a fifth "true" parameter*:

```
PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(newDocument, pdPage,
  PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
```

This causes the previously existing page content to be enveloped in a save-graphics-state/restore-graphics-state frame which resets the graphics state at the end to the original one to prevent changes in particular to the current transformation matrix from influencing one's new additions.

Ronak additionally according to a comment *per his requirement changed AppendMode **from APPEND to PREPEND** in 3rd param value.* This causes his changes to be added in the background, not the foreground.

So the final version of the `PDPageContentStream` construction is this:

```
PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(newDocument, pdPage,
  PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, true, true);
```